# Kotlin Paths.get gives me NoSuchFileException?

Tags: file, kotlin, path

**The problem:**

I am trying to move a file called "test.txt" from directory A to directory B.

```
    val sourcePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/DGH/Pictures/TestImages/test.txt");
    val targetPath = Paths.get("C:/Users/DGH/Pictures/TestOutputImages/test.txt");
    Files.move(sourcePath, targetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

I am completely sure that the text file exists at Pictures/TestImages/test.txt.

Even if I copy-paste the path directly in my file explorer, it will open the text file.

However, if I run this piece of code, it gives me a Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\DGH\Pictures\TestImages\test.txt.

**What have I tried:**

- Let the path starts with a slash, so

Paths.get("/C:/Users/DGH/Pictures/TestImages/test.txt");

- Replace the slash with a double backslash, so

Paths.get("C:\Users\DGH\Pictures\TestImages\test.txt");

Does someone have any idea why this is giving me a NoSuchFileException and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: If this is Windows, then the path separator should be ‘\’ — but note that that's a special character, so to get a string with a ‘\’ in it you'll need to enter ‘\\’ in the source.

Comment: @gidds that's not true. Forward slashes are fine, they are translated internally to backslashes.

I ran this code on my machine (with different paths, but same forward slashes), and it is working. zerk are you sure that the files are not symlinks? All imports stats with java.nio.file... ?